# StringCchCat function

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

Is it possible to use a string variable in place of `TEXT("\\*.txt")` in the following function in c++?

```
StringCchCat (szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*.txt"));
```

example:

```
string ext = "\\*.pdf";
StringCchCat (szDir, MAX_PATH, ext);
```

with VS C++ returns the error in compilation:

```
error C2664: 'StringCchCatW': can not convert parameter 3 from 'std :: string' to 'STRSAFE_LPCWSTR'
```

Comment: try `ext.c_str()` instead of `ext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it needs to be a wide character string:

```
std::wstring ext = L"\\*.pdf";
StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, ext.c_str());
```

Unless you are compiling without `UNICODE` defined, in which case you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ext` is not a wide character. Actually it is of type String as @billz pointed out. Looking at the [documentation for the StringCchCat function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it appears that Microsoft provide 3 overloaded forms of this function - one for standard chars, one for "TCHAR"s and one for wide characters. Either way a String isn't automatically cast to a char type and that is why you should use the c_str() function.